# Remove all digits from the string if it has more than 5

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have strings containing digits and I would like to remove the digits if there are more than 5 in the string.

For example modify `"string 58474847`" to `"string"`. But leave `"string 55"` as it is. The digits can be in the middle of the string as well.

Comment: Do you only want 5 *consecutive* digits removed? e.g., what about `"string 584 another string 7484"`? My answer only removes if there are more than 5 in a row, while @Wael's removes all digits if there are more than 5 total.

Comment: And what if there are multiple runs of >5 digits? Should they all be removed, or just the first? e.g., `"string 1234567 another string 9876543"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"{6,}"` to indicate "more than 5":

```
x <- c("string 58474847", "string 55")

gsub("[0-9]{6,}", "", x)
# "string "   "string 55"
```

If you also want to remove leading whitespace as in your example:

```
gsub("\\s*[0-9]{6,}", "", x)
# "string"   "string 55"
```

As pointed out by @ChrisRuehlemann, this will remove *all* runs of 6+ digits in each string. If you want to remove only the first run per string, use `sub()`.

```
x2 <- "string 1234567 another string 9876543"
gsub("\\s*[0-9]{5,}", "", x2)
# "string another string"

sub("\\s*[0-9]{5,}", "", x2)
# "string another string 9876543"
```

Comment: `gsub` is for potentially more than one match; `sub` is for exactly one match. Looks like there's just one match intended here

Comment: Good point, but I'm not sure what OP's intent is -- I've asked them in a comment.

Comment: `gsub(r'{\s\d{6,}}', '', x)` might be more concise

Answer (score 2):

you can use `stringr` and the functions `str_count` AND `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
st=c("string 58474847","string 55")
st=ifelse(str_count(st,"\\d")>5,str_replace_all(st,"\\d",""),st)
st 
[1] "string "   "string 55"
```

More detail here [stringr package](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/)
and a cheat sheet here [cheat sheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/main/strings.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)    
str_remove(x, "\\s\\d{6,}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by counting the number of digits in your string, then replace all times where there are more than 5 digits

```r
library(stringr)
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.1.3
test <- c('string 234567', 'string 55', 'str45ing 3656', 'string34567', '5string55555')
test[str_count(test, '[0-9]') > 5] <- 'string'
test
#> [1] "string"      "string 55"   "string"      "string34567" "string"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is not right. `string` was just an example. It could be anything, eg `stack 123456` `overflow 23456578`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `trimws` like below

```
> trimws(c("string 58474847", "string 55"), whitespace = "\\s\\d{6,}")
[1] "string"    "string 55"
```